# Calcular resto com 2 números BigInteger

Tags: java, matemática, bigint

Como calcular o resto com "%" a partir de dois números BigInteger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta usar o [método de `mod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#mod(java.math.BigInteger)) da classe `BigInteger`.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception  {
        BigInteger bi1, bi2, bi3;
        bi1 = new BigInteger("-100");
        bi2 = new BigInteger("3");

        bi3 = bi1.mod(bi2);
        System.out.println(bi3);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/63C5qf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ModBigInteger). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/ModBigInteger.java).